# What is responsible mail addr record?

Tags: dns, lookup, nslookup

I've been searching in google but I couldn't find documentation about it. E.g, using "nslookup" for look into soa registry of google.es you can see how responsible mail addr has the value of "dns-admin.google.com" for it. [image]

So, what is it and for what is it used for?

Comment: Shortcut: `nslookup -q=soa google.es`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The email address in [SOA RNAME](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/163971) is supposed to be the contact point for the person(s) managing the DNS zone (i.e. the domain and all its subdomains) – to report problems, etc. These days, AFAIK, it's not used for much anything (most people get the information from WHOIS instead).

The email address is written in DNS format with the local part as a subdomain (which, itself, is another grand plan that never quite succeeded – see also 'MB' record type), e.g. `fred.foobar@example.com` would be `fred\.foobar.example.com`. (Yes, that's a dot *in the middle* of a subdomain label.)

(See also: the 'RP' record type, used for designating "responsible persons" for individual hosts or subdomains. Also nearly extinct nowadays.)